# SDO_JOIN conversion to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, oracle-spatial, oracle-dbms

I make refactoring from Oracle to PostGIS and I found out that PostGIS doesn't support sdo_join.

How should I correct the statement below?

```sql
SELECT e.ID        AS EDGE1_ID,
       u.NODE_ID   AS NODE_ID,
       e.GEOM      AS EDGE1_GEOM,
       e.FTID      AS EDGE1_FTID,
       e.FID       AS EDGE1_FID,
       u.NODE_GEOM AS NODE_GEOM
FROM GRAPH_EDGE e,
     (SELECT j1.ID AS EDGE1_ID, j2.ID AS NODE_ID, j2.GEOM AS NODE_GEOM
      FROM TMP_EDGE j1,
           TMP_NODE j2,
          TABLE(sdo_join('TMP_EDGE', 'GEOM','TMP_NODE', 'GEOM', 'mask=EQUAL+CONTAINS')) x
   WHERE x.rowid1 = j1.ROWID 
     AND x.rowid2 = j2.ROWID 
     AND j1.ID != j2.ID) u
WHERE e.ID = u.EDGE1_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change `sdo_join` with a spatial join

```sql
SELECT e.ID        AS EDGE1_ID,
       u.NODE_ID   AS NODE_ID,
       e.GEOM      AS EDGE1_GEOM,
       e.FTID      AS EDGE1_FTID,
       e.FID       AS EDGE1_FID,
       u.NODE_GEOM AS NODE_GEOM
FROM GRAPH_EDGE e,
     (SELECT j1.ID AS EDGE1_ID, j2.ID AS NODE_ID, j2.GEOM AS NODE_GEOM
      FROM TMP_EDGE j1
           JOIN TMP_NODE j2
             ON ( 
               (st_equals(j1.geom, j2.geom) or st_contains(j1.geom, j2.geom)) 
               AND  j1.ID != j2.ID
             ) u
WHERE e.ID = u.EDGE1_ID;
```

Let's note that the entire sub-query could be remove and replaced with a join between `e` and `j1`

Comment: Thank you very much. It is interesting and nice solution. I think there is missing bracket but it is not important. As I understood for mask _EQUAL+CONTAINS_ is used join with methods ST_Equals or ST_Contains. So for ANYINTERACT will be used ST_Intersects only. But what condition should be used for OVERLAPBDYDISJOINT+OVERLAPBDYINTERSECT mask? I checked Oracle [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/spatial-relationships-and-filtering.htm#SPATL460) but I'm not sure which combination should be used...

Comment: What this? OVERLAPBDYDISJOINT = `ST_Intersects AND NOT ST_Contains` and OVERLAPBDYINTERSECT = `ST_Intersects AND ST_Contains`